# Displaying page Editing delay

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have been using Codeigniter for a while; but I have encountered a certain problem.
When editing my project, changes takes time to take place; I have tried to stop cache and clearing page caches without any success; this highly frustrate me. Someone help me please

Tank you

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution; in my hosting there was a Varnish cache turned on; the solution was to turn it off for my respective domain containing my codeigniter web application.

enjoy;